# Matplotlib: Formatting time on x-axis of stacked horizontal bar graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to graph the amounts of time a user spent on different tasks in a stacked horizontal bar graph using matplotlib. The x-axis is time. Each portion of the bar represents the amount of time spent on the task. However, I am getting an unexpected graph with incorrect formatting. The formatting of the graph requires me to zoom very far on the graph in order to see all of the bars.

The graph does resemble what I need, but at first it looks like this: [original graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQHgj.png)

And I have to zoom in very far in order to get this: [zoomed-in graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2Rq1.png)

The zoomed-in graph seems to have the correct proportions of the bars except for the first and last data points.

My data is a list of `timedelta` objects so they may be added together. I am converting them to `datetime` objects to graph the data.

The code that gives me undesired results is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import matplotlib.dates as dt

def sum_times(data, N):
    '''sums the first N datetime elements in a list
       changes from timedelta object to datetime object
    '''
    # initialize
    summ = datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
    for i in range(len(data[0:N])):
        summ += data[i]
    return summ

start_date = datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
times = [timedelta(0, 737), 
         timedelta(0, 110), 
         timedelta(0, 356), 
         timedelta(0, 171), 
         timedelta(0, 306)]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1, sharex=True, sharey=True)

ax1.set_title("Bug being fixed")
ax1.set_xlabel('time')
ax1.xaxis_date()

# the graph uses datetime objects
ax1.barh(1, times[0] + start_date)
ax1.barh(1, times[1] + start_date, left=sum_times(times, 1))
ax1.barh(1, times[2] + start_date, left=sum_times(times, 2))
ax1.barh(1, times[3] + start_date, left=sum_times(times, 3))
ax1.barh(1, times[4] + start_date, left=sum_times(times, 4))

ax1.set_xticks(range(1,10))   # arbitrary 

plt.show()
```

What can I do to change the formatting?

I have tried using `ax1.set_xticklabels()` with either `datetime` or `timedelta` objects, but I get the exception: `ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1`.

When I use

```
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(dt.MinuteLocator(interval=60))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dt.DateFormatter('%M:%S'))
```

the formatting is still incorrect.

I am using python 3.6, matplotlib, PyDev IDE, and Windows 8.

If there are any libraries that are better suited to display this sort of data or can supplement matplotlib/pyplot, I would appreciate a solution using one.

Also, I have tried using a loop to automate the calls to `ax1.barh(...)` but the graph window doesn't display and becomes unresponsive. Since I would like to graph larger data sets, I could use a more elegant solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the `pandas` library in Python might come in handy here, as the support for time series analysis and plotting is more native and intuitive than in `matplotlib` (which it is built on). If you have your data in the form of a CSV file, load the data into a dataframe using `df = pandas.read_csv(FILEPATH)` and plot with `df.plot()`. If you are looking for more complicated or responsive plots, definitely check out Plotly - you can simply import the library into python and make responsive graphs for time series and more pretty easily.

Comment: So does this solve the problem? You would need to tell how using pandas would help here. And why.

Comment: @rvd Would `dr.plot()` produce a horizontal bar graph? How could I use pandas for a stacked horizontal bar graph?

Comment: Yes - you can use `df.plot(y=DEPENDENT_VARIABLE, kind='barh')` to achieve this. To stack bars, you can use the same axis sharing method you use in `matplotlib` and provide an `ax` argument to the `df.plot()`

Comment: To add the x-label, use `plt.xlabel('times')` after the `plot()` call.
It seems you found my answer helpful - would mean a lot if you could upvote and select it :)

Comment: Thank you, your answer did indeed help me, but I found it to be somewhat vague.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the suggestion @rvd provided, I have come up with a somewhat better solution using pandas. It's still not ideal in terms of formatting, but I do not need to zoom in ridiculously far in order to see my graph and the data is proportional.

Here is the code that got it working a little better using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import matplotlib.dates as dt

times = [timedelta(0, 737), 
         timedelta(0, 110), 
         timedelta(0, 356), 
         timedelta(0, 171), 
         timedelta(0, 306)]

start_date = datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
times_datetime = [start_date + times[i] for i in range(len(times))]
# pandas requires numerical data on dependent axis
times_num = dt.date2num(times_datetime)
# to make times_num proportionally correct
for i in range(len(times_num)):
    times_num[i] -= dt.date2num(start_date)
    
df = pd.DataFrame([times_num], index=['bugs'])
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1, sharex=True, sharey=True)
df.plot(kind='barh', ax=ax1, stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

And this produces: [image: better graph]

The x-axis ticks may not be times, but the data visualization is more along the lines of what I'm looking for.

Thanks!